# SDL Tridion UI / Experience Manager - Modify the enable editing button

Tags: tridion

Is there a way to configure some settings around the 'SDL Tridion' button that is shown in the top left of the published website?

I'd like to go to town on it:

- Change the text from 'SDL Tridion' to something like 'Edit this page'
- Change the position in the page e.g. to bottom right
- Change the colour etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at concept of the skinning the Tridion CMS and apply the same for UI Experience Manager. You could find the UI themes `TRIDION_HOME\web\WebUI\Editors\SiteEdit\Themes` and possibly could add a new css for the placement of the button etc.

You could create a new css file like `MyCustom.css` and place it under the defalt Carbon. Once you have your new css file you need to update the `SiteEditEditor.cfg` file under `TRIDION_HOME\web\WebUI\Editors\SiteEdit\Configuration` to add new theme css file. Look for themefiles section in the config.

To change the default label, you need to change the EditorViewTitle data attribute value in `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Strings.resx` file located under `TRIDION_HOME\web\WebUI\WebRoot\App_GlobalResources`.

**NOTE::***Please note that updating .resx files may not be supported and not documented*.

I played with this while back and I am quite successful with the labels and themes, but did not pursue since it is not fully meeting my needs.

Skinning the CMS is documented at : http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_C4C14E4D601B4BE392ACE3B067426BB7

Comment: Just for my own clarity: modifying the resx is not documented anywhere, is it?

Comment: Cheers Ram, this is all fantastic information.  Not sure i'll be changing the resx, i'm sure i can put a bit of javascript to change the label in my custom SiteEdit theme.

Comment: No. Resx modifying is not documented anywhere.. updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough rep points to make a comment, so I am using an answer instead.
Thanks Ram for the details. 
I just tried to change the SDL Tridion button label, and I had to use the `StartButtonLabel` resource name in `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.Strings.resx` to make it work. The `EditorViewTitle` label appears as the browser page title, not on the start button.